# pySerial works in one script but not another

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, pyserial

**Now getting output, yet it is wrong** Post modified to reflect progress.

I have been reading the documentation as well as following links from this site. I was able to find a script that works in reading data from my Arduino serial output.

It is as follows:

```
import time
import serial

# configure the serial connections (the parameters differs on the device you are connecting to)
ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyACM0',
    baudrate=115200,
    parity=serial.PARITY_ODD,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO,
    bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS
)

ser.isOpen()

print 'Enter your commands below.\r\nInsert "exit" to leave the application.'

input=1
while 1 :
    # get keyboard input
    input = raw_input(">> ")
        # Python 3 users
        # input = input(">> ")
    if input == 'exit':
        ser.close()
        exit()
    else:
        # send the character to the device
        # (note that I happend a \r\n carriage return and line feed to the characters - this is requested by my device)
        ser.write(input + '\r\n')
        out = ''
        # let's wait one second before reading output (let's give device time to answer)
        time.sleep(1)
        while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
            out += ser.read(1)

        if out != '':
            print ">>" + out
```

The output window of Python opens and the code is executed. I am able to type 'exit' to exit or 'read' and a ton of lines from the Arduino serial monitor are now populated in the Python output window.

What I would like is to have the output from the Arduino to constantly be populated in the Python output window. (later I will try to plot the data using Matplotlib)

The code I used to attempt to read everything from the Arduinb is as such:

```
import time
import serial

# configure the serial connections (the parameters differs on the device you are connecting to)
ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyACM0',
    baudrate=115200,
    parity=serial.PARITY_ODD,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO,
    bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS
)



ser.isOpen()



input=1

while True:
    #First things first, lets wait for data prior to reading
    time.sleep(1)
    if (ser.inWaiting()>0):

        myArduinoData = ser.read()
        print myArduinoData
```

However, when I use the above code the Python execution hangs and I get no output from the serial monitor. **This was now corrected by the above code and the community help**

The new problem is the output only giving a single digit value and not the two to three digit value output to the Arduino serial monitor.

**thanks to** @jalo **I was able to get the values in question by specifying a byte value in my inWaiting and ser.read statements. The change is as follows:**

```
(ser.inWaiting()>4): 

ser = ser.read(4)
```

Thank you.

Comment: may be time.sleep(1) in your first example is giving the code the time to settle things. You might try it in the second example.

Comment: Have you tried the method ser.read() instead ser.readline()? It seems to be hanging because it is not able to read any data... Besidess, use while True, as it is more Pythonic

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I have placed a time.sleep(1) command after the 'while (1==1):' command and before the 'if (ser.inWaiting()>0):' command, still nothing. I am modifying my post now

Comment: @Jalo GREAT! I changed to 'while True' and also changed the ser.readline() command to ser.read() I am now getting output. However, this is the incorrect output, I am getting single digit values which do not reflect the output on the Arduinos end. ie, the values are: 
4
,
1
4
4
,
1
... and they should be heart rate values, usualy 68-120 for me

Comment: try writing an empty line to serial after the sleep, ser.write('\r\n')

Comment: You have a message integrity problem... You must order your data packages in some way, an for this purpose you have to know how you are sending data from arduino... For example, if the data is always 4-byte length, you can  put as a condition  `if (ser.inWaiting()>4):  ser.read(4)`

Comment: However, there are better solutions, though more complicated.  e.g. Implementing a communication protocol in order to know where a package begins and ends

Comment: @LuisMuñoz Adding the write to the empty line after the sleep function causes it to hang again.

Comment: nice! you know how to break it :D

Comment: @JamesHayek  time.sleep() is useless

Comment: You can't use any serial port if `OS` isn't open first. How to send a `weekup` or `config` message to BUS_LINE. Not a solution but a trciky : Open your app and push your MCU reset button, will be work !(of-course we talking about LINUX)